# Can I use an instantiated Object as an Array Key?

Tags: php, arrays, object

For example:

```
$product = new Product("cat");

if(isset($sales[$product])){
     $sales[$product]++;
}
else{
     $sales[$product] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

You could give each instance a unique ID or override [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) such that it returns something unique and do e.g.

```
$array[(string) $instance] = 42;
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

```
$product = new Product("cat");
$sales = new SplObjectStorage();
if(isset($sales[$product])){
     $sales[$product]++;
}
else{
     $sales[$product] = 1;
}
```

It's not a real array, but has a decent amount of array-like functionality and syntax. However, due to it being an object, it behaves like a misfit in php due to its odd foreach behavior, and its incompatibility with all the native php array functions. Sometimes you'll find it useful to convert it to a real array via

```
$arr = iterator_to_array($sales);
```

so it plays nice with the rest of your codebase.

Answer (score 16):

There is a **spl_object_hash** function for getting unique object id as string, which can be used as array key. http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php

Comment: Actually from the docs: When an object is destroyed, its **hash may be reused** for other objects.
So generally its is better idea to use SplObjectStorage as suggested by goat.

Answer (score 4):

Only [integers and strings are allowed as array keys](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You could write a class that implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) if you absolutely need that functionality.

Comment: It won't allow you to use object as an array key. The only thing it allows is to treat object as an array, so the properties of the object will be keys

Comment: It *will* allow you to use objects as keys. See http://pastebin.com/fzqeFswJ for an example implementation.

Comment: I see what you mean, it makes sense. I meant that it will not allow you to use objects as an _array_ key. But yes, it will allow you to use objects as a key of ArrayAccess object

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, and that `SplObjectStorage` has some weird behaviour (e.g. when looping with `foreach`).

As of today, there is this library I wrote called `linked-hash-map` (https://github.com/tonix-tuft/linked-hash-map) which implements an associative array/hash map/hash table in PHP and allows you to use any PHP data type for the key:

```php
<?php

use LinkedHashMap\LinkedHashMap;

$map = new LinkedHashMap();
$map[true] = 'bool (true)';
$map[false] = 'bool (false)';
$map[32441] = 'int (32441)';
$map[-32441] = 'int (-32441)';
$map[2147483647] = 'int (2147483647)';
$map[-2147483648] = 'int (-2147483648)';
$map[PHP_INT_MAX - 100] = 'int (PHP_INT_MAX - 100)';
$map[PHP_INT_MIN] = 'int (PHP_INT_MIN)';
$map[0.5] = 'float/double (0.5)';
$map[-0.5] = 'float/double (-0.5)';
$map[123891.73] = 'float/double (123891.73)';
$map[-123891.73] = 'float/double (-123891.73)';
$map[PHP_INT_MAX + 10] = 'float/double (PHP_INT_MAX + 10)';
$map[PHP_INT_MIN - 10] = 'float/double (PHP_INT_MIN - 10)';
$map['abc'] = 'string (abc)';
$map["abcdef"] = "string (abcdef)";
$map['hfudsh873hu2ifl'] = "string (hfudsh873hu2ifl)";
$map["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"] =
  'string (The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)';
$map[[1, 2, 3]] = 'array ([1, 2, 3])';
$map[['a', 'b', 'c']] = "array (['a', 'b', 'c'])";
$map[[1, 'a', false, 5, true, [1, 2, 3, ['f', 5, []]]]] =
  "array ([1, 'a', false, 5, true, [1, 2, 3, ['f', 5, []]]])";

class A {
}
$objA = new A();
$map[$objA] = "object (new A())";

// You can even use file handles/resources:
$fp = fopen(__DIR__ . '/private_local_file', 'w');
$map[$fp] = "resource (fopen())";

$ch = curl_init();
$map[$ch] = "resource (curl_init())";

// All the values can be retrieved later using the corresponding key, e.g.:
var_dump($map[[1, 2, 3]]); // "array ([1, 2, 3])"
var_dump($map[$objA]); // "object (new A())"
var_dump($map[$ch]); // "resource (curl_init())"
```

Answer (score 1):

You finally can use objects as array keys in PHP 8.0+. But that's a bit of a lie. It won't be regular arrays you're using, but [the new WeakMap class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.weakmap.php).

Declare a `new WeakMap();` and then you can pack it full of objects as keys. The advantage of using this over any `Spl`-based trick, is that `WeakMap` is better on memory leaks. The "weak" part refers to the fact that the object's reference in the map is "weak" and will not prevent the object from getting garbage-collected once it's no longer in-scope. The `WeakMap` will automatically remove the object from itself.

Here's [a good run-through](https://php.watch/articles/practical-weakmap) on use cases.

The [PHP RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/weak_maps) is a good read, too.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a simple predefined classes made with `new stdClass()` it may be valid option to use the json representation of this class with `json_encode`.

```
$product = new stdClass();
$product->brand = "Acme";
$product->name = "Patator 3.14";

$product_key = json_encode($product);

if(isset($sales[$product_key])){
     $sales[$product_key]++;
}
else{
    $sales[$product_key] = 1;
}
```

But keep in mind that the equality of two objects is always a business model choice and must be carefully designed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two arrays:

```
Array 1 contains the keys:   |  Array 2 contains the values
+--------+-------------+     |  +--------+------------+
| index: | value:      |     |  | index: | value:     |
| 0      | Object(key) |     |  | 0      | sth(value) |
| 1      | Object(key) |     |  | 1      | sth(value) |
+--------+-------------+     |  +--------+------------+
```

You search for the Object in array 1,
then you pick the index of that Object
use it as index for array 2 and
=> get the value

in php code

```
public function getValue($ObjectIndexOfYourArray){
  foreach(array1 as $key => $value) {
    if($value == ObjectIndexOfYourArray){
      return array2[$key];
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps