# Retrieve an associative array value with a variable as key

Tags: php, associative-array

Here's some code that I have trouble with. I don't know why, I feel I have used this code many times without any problems.

```
$people['firstname'] = "Fred";
$t = "firstname";
echo $people[$t] ;
```

echo returns nothing, whereas i expect it to return Fred.

Thanks for your help, Marc

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code at all. Double check grammar, spelling and character case.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Pasted your code verbatim in a PHP 5.3 project. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the code is ok. Just have to find now why it doesn't work on my page.

Comment: @Marco I have a similar problem. Did you resolve yours? If yes, can you tell what the problem was?

Comment: I have same problem the array return noting when I use variable  `$CCodes2=$CCodes[$country];` but when i use `echo $CCodes["LY"];` gives me correct value here is the array `$CCodes=array("BH"=>"BHD","DZ"=>"DZD","EG"=>"EGP","IQ"=>"IQD","JO"=>"JOD","KW"=>"KWD","LB"=>"LBP","LY"=>"LYD",
"MA"=>"MAD","OM"=>"OMR","QA"=>"QAR","SA"=>"SAR","SD"=>"SDG","TN"=>"TND","YE"=>"YER","MR"=>"MRO");`

Comment: Just throwing this out there: I ran into a similar problem, but it turned out that I was using an object to index into the array, not a string. As others have noted, in this exact example there is no problem since $t is a string. But similar-looking code may have issues. In my case I was using the result of "simplexml_load_string" to use what I thought was a string as the key, but turned out to be an object. It was confusing because when I printed the object, it came out as a readable string. When I cast the key to a string using "(string)" before using it as a key, then everything worked.

Comment: As a reference to my previous comment, this link indicates how to use an object as a key to an array:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642980/can-i-use-an-instantiated-object-as-an-array-key

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this isn't working for you.

```
$people['firstname'] = 'testvalue';

$key = 'firstname';

$value = $people[$key];

echo $value;
```

Works as expected, echos out "testvalue"

Double check your spelling and be consistent with your ticks (purely stylistic, I'm sure.)

Answer (score 1):

OK I found solution for my code, looks like variable contains, none ASCII character so I had to remove them, to make it works.

```
$country = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $country);
$CCodes2=$CCodes[$country];
```

You should check your php file encoding, e.g if you are use WYSIWYG editor or formatted text, make sue remove any of these none ASCII text before paste it .

Comment: this solved my issue

Comment: OG, my English were horrible back than, I fix some mistakes I typed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass associative array value as variable . this is working for me

```
@$username=$_POST['username'];
@$password=$_POST['password'];

$result=array(
'username'=> "".$username."",
'password'=> "".$password.""
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$params_to_json = '{"' . str_replace(['=', '&'], ['":"', '","'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) . '"}';
$json_to_array = json_decode($params_to_json, true) ?? array(); 
extract($json_to_string); // Converts array keys into variable names and array values into variable value
```

---

As a function:

```
function url_params()
{
    $params_to_json = '{"' . str_replace(['=', '&'], ['":"', '","'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) . '"}';
    return json_decode($params_to_json, true) ?? array();
}
extract(url_params());
```

---

For example URL: **example.com?id=3**

```
echo $id //3
```