# Check if array of checkboxes are checked from a form (PHP)

Tags: php, forms

I realize this is a question that has been asked before ("Cannot use [] for reading"), but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the answer and how to fix my particular function.

```
function check_required_checkbox($checkbox_name, $error, $is_multiple_checkboxes)
{
    global $error_msgs;
    if ($is_multiple_checkboxes == true)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$checkbox_name][]))
        {
            $error_msgs[] = $error;
        }
    else if ($is_multiple_checkboxes == false)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$checkbox_name]))
        {
            $error_msgs[] = $error;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem line is 6, `!isset($_POST[$checkbox_name][])`, and I'm not understanding how the correct way I should write it.  I saw instances of using brackets but `!isset($_POST[{$checkbox_name}][])` isn't correct either.

When I have multiple checkboxes that use `name="radda[]"`, I want my function to check that all of the checkboxes with a specific name are checked, and if not, add `$error` to the `$error_msgs[]` array.

**EDIT:**
I discussed with the department that was requesting a rewrite of the old form.  Instead of using checkboxes, I switched it to a list of all of the borrower's rights and responsibilities, and then used a radio button below the list to ask the user to select "yes" or "no" on whether they read the list.  Then I made it required to select "yes" or "no" and added validation that if "no" was selected, they wouldn't be able to submit the application.  This was *far* easier than trying to make a bunch of checkboxes required.  I do appreciate the help that everyone offered though.

Comment: $checkbox name is defined? Try a print_r($_REQUEST); just to see all the variables sent in the request.

Comment: If you call a set of checkboxes `name="radda[]"` then you will recieve an array called `$_POST['radda']` how many occurances depends upon how many of the checkboxes where actually checked. ___Unchecked checkboxes are not returned in the array___

Comment: @RiggsFolly so in order to check that all of the checkboxes in a group are checked, I'd use ```if (isset($_POST['radda']) < 8)) { $error_msgs[] = $error; }```?

Comment: No. Check if anything has been checked using `if (isset($_POST['radda']))` check how may have been checked using `if (count($_POST['radda']) < 8) {` but remember there will only be an item in the array IF a checkbox is checked. If only 2 checkboxes are checked you will only get 2 items in the array

Comment: @RiggsFolly but if I know beforehand how many checkboxes need to be checked, I can check that the count is correct, and proceed, right? I think I can modify my function to pass a parameter for the amount of checkboxes, and use that in the ```count``` conditional.  The goal is to make sure that ALL of the checkboxes within the name group ```radda[]``` are checked.

Comment: Yes in that case you can. I have to ask why you are giving a user a checkbox if they have to check them, but thats your decidion

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not the best way of doing it, I admit.  It's for "borrower's rights and responsibilities" on a loan application, and we need them to click the check boxes to say that they've read the all of rights and responsibilities.  Kinda of an annoying way to do it, but it makes it easier for us to verify that, "hey, it says you read all of the borrower's rights and responsibilities."

Comment: I would: create an array of '$cbxRadda[]' where the key was the checkbox values that are set to false. I would then go through the $_POST['radda'] array setting the appropriate  `'$cbxRadda[]` entries to true. It is now trivial to work out what to do for each `Radda` checkbox?

Comment: @RyanVincent I kind of understand what you're getting at.  I have the values set to each borrower's right/responsibility, but I suppose if I just need to _list_ the writing on the page, I don't need to set the values to them as well.  Based on what you're saying, it's overkill.  So, I set the values to false on the form, and then check to see if they're true in the form validation?

Comment: @RyanVincent There's something I'm missing in the logic, but I think what you suggested would work.  I'll have to toy with it a bit.

Comment: The issue is that _only set checkboxes get returned_  You need a list of **all the checkboxes on the form** to compare what was returned against all the previous values?

Comment: I do have an array created that has all of the borrower's rights and responsibilities, and then on the form creation, I just cycle through the array.  I'd be able to use that array as the list of all the checkboxes, couldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you need.
Try to define the $checkbox_name variable and then access the POST.

```
$checkbox_name = 'radda';

if (isset($_POST[$checkbox_name]) && !is_array($_POST[$checkbox_name]))
{
   $error_msgs[] = $error;
}
```

Something like that should work.

Here is a similar thread: [Retrieve an associative array value with a variable as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105756/retrieve-an-associative-array-value-with-a-variable-as-key)

Comment: Not quite.  My function was originally written that way, but it was only checking that ONE checkbox among a group was checked.  I need the function to check that all checkboxes in a group are checked.  Normally I could use ```$_POST['radda'][]``` (I think), and it'd work, but not if I'm passing a variable as the key?

Comment: what about checking if its an array? you can use is_array($_POST['radda']) after the isset but without the last []. I've just updated the answer with that condition.

Comment: ```$_POST``` is always an array though.  Checking if it's an array is redundant.

Comment: Of course $_POST is an array, but the VARIABLE it contains can be an array or not, that's why is checking. Anyways what do you need? to check if a value of the post array is an array, right?

Comment: To check that an array of checkboxes from a form are all checked.

I have a group of checkboxes on a form, which all have the same name, ```name="radda[]"```, and I need to make sure that all of them are checked because they're required.  I know this can be validated in javascript, but I have to account for screen readers which most don't have javascript capabilities.

Comment: I realize now I should have had that in my question above.  My intention was to fix my function, but I see now that I have the logic incorrect, so my ultimate goal of checking to see if all checkboxes are checked wouldn't be solved with my above function, and would actually require different logic entirely.  (don't try asking a question that's not completely understood on no caffeine, lesson learned)

Comment: Just an idea. Define all the checkboxes in a php array. Then render them iterating it. When you get the results you can compare the ones checked with the ones rendered.