# ErrorException (E_WARNING) Illegal offset type in authManager.php laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel-6.2

I am trying to make a login function for my Laravel app where register is working normally and the data is getting added in MySQL tables. But when I'm logging in with the credentials, it shows me

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) Illegal offset type in  return
>   $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);

Please help me in this

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

I have also added the new function code as

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    if (empty($name)) {
        $name = $this->getDefaultDriver();
    }
    echo 'Argument type: '. gettype($name);
    var_dump($name); 
    if (key_exists($name, $this->guards)) {
        $result = $this->guards[$name];
    } else {
        $result = $this->resolve($name);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Now it is showing me this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcDzz.jpg)
It was showing in key_exists() first argument should be an integer or string then I added the var_dump() method to know about the type of $name.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    if (empty($name)) {
        $name = $this->getDefaultDriver();
    }

    if (key_exists($name, $this->guards)) {
        $result = $this->guards[$name];
    } else {
        $result = $this->resolve($name);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Now it is giving me a new error ErrorException (E_WARNING)
key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in the line    if (key_exists($name, $this->guards)) {
        $result = $this->guards[$name];

Comment: @shubhanshu put before `if (key_exists...` this line: `echo 'Argument type: '. gettype($name);` and write back what the type was. You may also use `var_dump($name);` to get the information about the var `$name` you have a problem with.

Comment: it is just giving me a whole junk of info without solving the problem..

Comment: @shubhanshu the junk is not a junk at all. It is a key information to solve the problem. Edit you question and add information about the `$name` type that causes the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the information you wanted please help me through.

Comment: @shubhanshu the problem is you try to check if there is a key in array but the key you pass to the key_exists() is an object. An array in [PHP cannot have an object as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642980/can-i-use-an-instantiated-object-as-an-array-key). The variable you pass is an JSON object, probably you forget to use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter set to `true` and taking some string out of the array it returns.